# Windows Phone 7 - Show "SIM Applications" page via code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, show

How can i show the SIM Applications page via code? I searched in Tasks but i didn't found anything useful! Thank you for paying attention to my question^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not a Task that matches your requirement then it is not going to be possible to launch this section of the OS.

Comment: I was waiting for this answer. Thanks anyway!